# Applications under virtual host?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

We are trying to set-up the following scenario in Apache:

http://intranet.site.com -> /var/www/html/intranet

http://intranet.site.com/app1 -> /var/www/html/app1

http://intranet.site.com/app2 -> /var/www/html/app2

Is this possible? How do we configure our httpd.conf? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure mod_alias is enabled and then inside your VirtualHost:

```
Alias /app1 /var/www/html/app1
Alias /app2 /var/www/html/app2
```